# Android ( GestureOverlayView ) usage

Tags: android

I want to know, How can I implement **GestureOverLayView** in android. I tried by looking some code on internet but I have not found any **convenient** and **easy** way to implement that. Please give me some **examples** through **code**.

Comment: Could you expand on this to include what research you have done and why they were insufficient

Comment: To avoid the question being closed without being answered, please refer to [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

public class GestureTest extends Activity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {
        private GestureLibrary gestureLib;

```
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView = new GestureOverlayView(this);
            View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, null);
            gestureOverlayView.addView(inflate);
            gestureOverlayView.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
            gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
            if (!gestureLib.load()) {
                    finish();
            }
            setContentView(gestureOverlayView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
            ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);
            for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
                    if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                    }
            }
    }
```

}

Comment: @Amida.....i am getting error on R.raw.gestures......because I have not created any gesture file in raw folder.....can u please give me that also.